# android: exception moving through menu

Tags: android, exception, random

in my activities i've a bottom menu loaded using inflate (the menu is an `horizontalScrollView` with some buttons (one selected and one deselected for each activity)).

Moving quickly throught this menu, sometimes i get an exception (the point is random) and seems that for some reason, android has killed something so is not available for my activity.

error logs:

```
12-12 09:24:24.389: I/Process(480): Sending signal. PID: 480 SIG: 9
12-12 09:24:24.430: I/ActivityManager(81): Process com.apia.selfnettest (pid 480) has died.
12-12 09:24:24.439: I/WindowManager(81): WIN DEATH: Window{405b6c28 com.apia.selfnettest/com.apia.selfnettest.MainClass paused=false}
12-12 09:24:24.459: E/InputDispatcher(81): channel '407da4a8 com.apia.selfnettest/com.apia.selfnettest.MainClass (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
12-12 09:24:24.459: E/InputDispatcher(81): channel '407da4a8 com.apia.selfnettest/com.apia.selfnettest.MainClass (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
12-12 09:24:24.609: I/WindowManager(81): WIN DEATH: Window{40613eb8 com.apia.selfnettest/com.apia.selfnettest.MainClass paused=false}
12-12 09:24:24.769: I/WindowManager(81): WIN DEATH: Window{405fc890 com.apia.selfnettest/com.apia.selfnettest.MainClass paused=false}
12-12 09:24:24.960: I/WindowManager(81): WIN DEATH: Window{409d4d48 com.apia.selfnettest/com.apia.selfnettest.MainClass paused=false}
12-12 09:24:25.030: I/WindowManager(81): WIN DEATH: Window{408c5d58 com.apia.selfnettest/com.apia.selfnettest.ContactOffline paused=false}
12-12 09:24:25.189: I/WindowManager(81): WIN DEATH: Window{408f4090 com.apia.selfnettest/com.apia.selfnettest.InformationOffline paused=false}
12-12 09:24:25.289: I/WindowManager(81): WIN DEATH: Window{406f0470 com.apia.selfnettest/com.apia.selfnettest.MainClass paused=false}
12-12 09:24:25.459: I/WindowManager(81): WIN DEATH: Window{4054e0b8 com.apia.selfnettest/com.apia.selfnettest.MainClass paused=false}
12-12 09:24:25.579: I/WindowManager(81): WIN DEATH: Window{406f7be0 com.apia.selfnettest/com.apia.selfnettest.MainClass paused=false}
12-12 09:24:25.679: I/WindowManager(81): WIN DEATH: Window{409eb980 com.apia.selfnettest/com.apia.selfnettest.MainClass paused=false}
12-12 09:24:25.819: I/ActivityManager(81): Start proc com.apia.selfnettest for activity com.apia.selfnettest/.MainClass: pid=520 uid=10034 gids={3003, 1006, 1015}
12-12 09:24:25.829: I/WindowManager(81): WINDOW DIED Window{407da4a8 com.apia.selfnettest/com.apia.selfnettest.MainClass paused=false}
12-12 09:24:25.859: I/WindowManager(81): WIN DEATH: Window{40774410 com.apia.selfnettest/com.apia.selfnettest.MainClass paused=false}
12-12 09:24:25.899: E/InputDispatcher(81): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=160, events=0x8
12-12 09:24:25.899: E/InputDispatcher(81): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=163, events=0x8
12-12 09:24:25.899: E/InputDispatcher(81): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=166, events=0x8
12-12 09:24:25.899: E/InputDispatcher(81): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=171, events=0x8
12-12 09:24:25.899: E/InputDispatcher(81): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=174, events=0x8
12-12 09:24:25.899: E/InputDispatcher(81): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=175, events=0x8
12-12 09:24:25.899: E/InputDispatcher(81): channel '406dfd88 com.apia.selfnettest/com.apia.selfnettest.MainClass (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
12-12 09:24:25.899: E/InputDispatcher(81): channel '406dfd88 com.apia.selfnettest/com.apia.selfnettest.MainClass (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
12-12 09:24:25.961: I/WindowManager(81): WIN DEATH: Window{407713a0 com.apia.selfnettest/com.apia.selfnettest.MainClass paused=false}
12-12 09:24:25.979: I/WindowManager(81): WIN DEATH: Window{409345c0 com.apia.selfnettest/com.apia.selfnettest.MainClass paused=false}
12-12 09:24:26.090: I/WindowManager(81): WIN DEATH: Window{408ab168 com.apia.selfnettest/com.apia.selfnettest.MainClass paused=false}
12-12 09:24:26.130: I/WindowManager(81): WIN DEATH: Window{40892f20 com.apia.selfnettest/com.apia.selfnettest.MainClass paused=false}
12-12 09:24:26.171: I/WindowManager(81): WIN DEATH: Window{406dfd88 com.apia.selfnettest/com.apia.selfnettest.MainClass paused=false}
12-12 09:24:26.199: W/WindowManager(81): Failed looking up window
12-12 09:24:26.199: W/WindowManager(81): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@407da2c8 does not exist
12-12 09:24:26.199: W/WindowManager(81):    at com.android.server.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8174)
12-12 09:24:26.199: W/WindowManager(81):    at com.android.server.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8165)
12-12 09:24:26.199: W/WindowManager(81):    at com.android.server.WindowManagerService$WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied(WindowManagerService.java:7024)
12-12 09:24:26.199: W/WindowManager(81):    at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:381)
12-12 09:24:26.199: W/WindowManager(81):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
12-12 09:24:26.199: I/WindowManager(81): WIN DEATH: null
12-12 09:24:26.199: I/WindowManager(81): WIN DEATH: Window{4093bfb0 com.apia.selfnettest/com.apia.selfnettest.MainClass paused=false}
12-12 09:24:26.260: I/WindowManager(81): WIN DEATH: Window{408d2a28 com.apia.selfnettest/com.apia.selfnettest.MainClass paused=false}
12-12 09:24:26.300: I/WindowManager(81): WIN DEATH: Window{408a49e8 com.apia.selfnettest/com.apia.selfnettest.MainClass paused=false}
12-12 09:24:26.311: I/WindowManager(81): WIN DEATH: Window{40884570 com.apia.selfnettest/com.apia.selfnettest.MainClass paused=false}
12-12 09:24:26.319: E/InputDispatcher(81): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=181, events=0x8
12-12 09:24:26.330: E/InputDispatcher(81): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=184, events=0x8
12-12 09:24:26.330: E/InputDispatcher(81): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=187, events=0x8
12-12 09:24:26.330: E/InputDispatcher(81): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=190, events=0x8
12-12 09:24:26.330: E/InputDispatcher(81): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=195, events=0x8
12-12 09:24:26.330: E/InputDispatcher(81): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=196, events=0x8
12-12 09:24:26.330: E/InputDispatcher(81): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=198, events=0x8
12-12 09:24:26.330: E/InputDispatcher(81): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=202, events=0x8
12-12 09:24:26.330: I/InputDispatcher(81): Dropping event because there is no touched window or focused application.
12-12 09:24:26.330: I/InputDispatcher(81): Dropping event because there is no touched window or focused application.
12-12 09:24:26.340: I/InputDispatcher(81): Dropping event because there is no touched window or focused application.
12-12 09:24:26.340: I/InputDispatcher(81): Dropping event because there is no touched window or focused application.
12-12 09:24:26.340: I/InputDispatcher(81): Dropping event because there is no touched window or focused application.
12-12 09:24:26.340: I/InputDispatcher(81): Dropping event because there is no touched window or focused application.
12-12 09:24:26.340: I/InputDispatcher(81): Dropping event because there is no touched window or focused application.
12-12 09:24:26.349: I/InputDispatcher(81): Dropping event because there is no touched window or focused application.
12-12 09:24:26.349: I/InputDispatcher(81): Dropping event because there is no touched window or focused application.
12-12 09:24:26.349: I/InputDispatcher(81): Dropping event because there is no touched window or focused application.
12-12 09:24:26.349: I/InputDispatcher(81): Dropping event because there is no touched window or focused application.
12-12 09:24:26.349: I/InputDispatcher(81): Dropping event because there is no touched window or focused application.
12-12 09:24:26.349: I/InputDispatcher(81): Dropping event because there is no touched window or focused application.
12-12 09:24:26.359: I/InputDispatcher(81): Dropping event because there is no touched window or focused application.
12-12 09:24:26.359: I/InputDispatcher(81): Dropping event because there is no touched window or focused application.
12-12 09:24:26.359: I/InputDispatcher(81): Dropping event because there is no touched window or focused application.
12-12 09:24:26.359: I/InputDispatcher(81): Dropping event because there is no touched window or focused application.
12-12 09:24:26.380: I/InputDispatcher(81): Dropping event because there is no touched window or focused application.
12-12 09:24:26.380: I/InputDispatcher(81): Dropping event because there is no touched window or focused application.
12-12 09:24:26.380: I/InputDispatcher(81): Dropping event because there is no touched window or focused application.
12-12 09:24:26.539: I/InputDispatcher(81): Dropping event because there is no touched window or focused application.
12-12 09:24:26.630: I/jdwp(520): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
12-12 09:24:27.030: D/AndroidRuntime(520): Shutting down VM
12-12 09:24:27.030: W/dalvikvm(520): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
12-12 09:24:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(520): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-12 09:24:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(520): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.apia.selfnettest/com.apia.selfnettest.MainClass}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-12 09:24:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
12-12 09:24:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
12-12 09:24:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-12 09:24:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
12-12 09:24:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-12 09:24:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-12 09:24:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-12 09:24:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-12 09:24:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-12 09:24:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-12 09:24:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-12 09:24:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-12 09:24:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(520): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-12 09:24:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at com.apia.utils.LibLayout.determineScreenDensity(LibLayout.java:1273)
12-12 09:24:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at com.apia.utils.LibLayout.isXLargeLayout(LibLayout.java:1310)
12-12 09:24:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at com.apia.selfnettest.MainClass.onCreate(MainClass.java:191)
12-12 09:24:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-12 09:24:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
12-12 09:24:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(520):  ... 11 more
12-12 09:24:27.059: W/ActivityManager(81):   Force finishing activity com.apia.selfnettest/.MainClass
12-12 09:24:27.580: W/ActivityManager(81): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{4071c7f0 com.apia.selfnettest/.MainClass}
12-12 09:24:30.865: W/ActivityManager(81): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
```

this is the function that generate the error:

```
 public static int determineScreenDensity() {
        //0: low density
        //1: medium density
        //2: high density
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((Activity) LibBanking.AppContext).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        int density = metrics.densityDpi;

        if (density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH) {
            return 3;
        }
        else if (density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH) {
            return 2;
        }
        else if (density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM) {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            return 1;
        }

    }
```

---

and notice that `LibBanking.AppContext` is set in each `activity` in this way:

```
LibBanking.AppContext = this;
```

thank you in advance....

Comment: What happens at this line : `com.apia.utils.LibLayout.determineScreenDensity(LibLayout.java:1273)`.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 12-12 09:24:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(520): at com.apia.utils.LibLayout.determineScreenDensity(LibLayout.java:1273) 12-12 09:24:27.050: E/AndroidRuntime(520): at com.apia.utils.LibLayout.isXLargeLayout(LibLayout.java:1310): yes, post these lines to see what's going on there.

Comment: public static boolean isXLargeLayout(Activity myActivity, Context ctx) {
     
     boolean res = false;
     int myDensity = determineScreenDensity(); 
 return res;
    }

Comment: the determineScreenDensity() function is described in my first post...